# What should be used to insulate around the interior brick of chimney that is next to drywall?

Tags: insulation

There is a center ledger, covered in painted drywall - next to the centered brick chimney(in the center of the house).  There's a gap between the ledger and the chimney.  Is "Great Stuff" safe to use to insulate this?  Isn't there a "Great Stuff" of similar product that is fire retardant?  The chimney doesn't get hot, but it can get warm when temperatures get extreme.

Comment: The Great Stuff made for fire retardation is more flammable than the regular Great stuff - which is pretty flammable itself - search youtube for this.  I would use roxul.

Answer (score 1):

The clearance for combustible materials to a properly built masonry chimney like you describe would be 0"; no clearance required.

I would use just about anything you want and worry more about getting your chimney inspected and cleaned on a regular basis.